# How to prevent inserting in database if value is equal to zero?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on a project and then I got this problem. Here is the scenario, when I insert in database, it must not insert if the value is zero ,,but then when I check my database ,there are zeros being inserted, I don't know where I go wrong or I just missed the trapping that if the value is equal zero then it must not insert.

Here is the code :

```
$ref_array = explode(',' , $ref_number);
$po_array = explode(',' , $po_number);
$inv_array = explode(',' , $inv_number);
$asn_array = explode(',' , $asn_number);
$adj_array = explode(',' , $adj_number);
$amount_array = explode(',' , $amount);

// count the number of po,invoice,asn and adj
if(count($po_array) != count($ref_array) || count($inv_array) != count($ref_array) || count($asn_array) != count($ref_array) || count($adj_array) != count($ref_array) || count($ref_array) != count($amount_array)){

    foreach ($ref_array as $i => $ref_num){
        $po_num = isset($po_array[$i]) ? $po_array[$i] : '' ; //leave blank there is no $po_array[$i]
        $inv_num = isset($inv_array[$i]) ? $inv_array[$i] : '';
        $asn_num = isset($asn_array[$i]) ? $asn_array[$i] : '' ;
        $adj_num = isset($adj_array[$i]) ? $adj_array[$i] : '' ;
        $amount_num = isset($amount_array[$i])? $amount_array[$i] : '';



        if(intval($ref_num) != 0 ){

            $conn->query ("INSERT INTO transaction_detail (`transaction_id`,`ref_number`,`po_number`,`inv_number`,`asn_number`,`adj_number`,`amount`)
                    VALUES ('$transaction_id','$ref_num','$po_num','$inv_num','$asn_num','$adj_num','$amount_num') " );
        }
    }  
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: why you are not use `if(($ref_num) >0 ){`

Comment: can you provide sample input/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just remove intval form your condition because it is use to  `Get the integer value of a variable`.

Second check `$ref_num` variable is greater then zero

you condition would be

```
if(($ref_num) >0 ){
```

Also read [intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

Answer (score 0):

Check the transaction_detail table whether you have put default value as 0 for po_number field.